# Timeout on Google Home using Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm developing my own bot and in one instance I prompt the user to take a measurement, and then wait for their reply. Currently, my bot times out before the user even has time to take the measurement. Suggestions on how to extend the timeout period?

Comment: Hi user10687878, is it possible for you to leave code snippet? It may help others to understand your question better and improve the turnaround greatly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend the timeout period, and you cannot extend how many "no-input" events occur before the Action closes.

There are a couple of possible approaches to a solution:

- You can end the conversation and instruct the user to re-start the conversation with the measurement by providing you the information as part of a deep link. (Or just prompt them when they return to the conversation.)
- You can play some "hold music" by using a Media response. When the media ends, you will get a notice, so you can play more music until the user gives you a response.

Comment: hmm thanks for the insight. however- I am worried that while the music is playing and the user is having a conversation with someone else in the room it will be confused. I want to avoid using paper and pen though...

Comment: It isn't listening during the hold music portion, unless triggered with the hot word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<break time="5" />` in SSML.

`` conv.ask(`<speak><break time="5" /></speak>`); ``

https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/ssml